# How can I cache a doctrine query?

Tags: php, caching, symfony-1.4

In the web debug toolbar I see 109 SQL queries for my index.php.

One query is used 40 times:

```
Doctrine::getTable('Configuration')->getConfiguration();
```

This is because of many components and the action:

```
public function executeImpress(sfWebRequest $request) {
   Doctrine::getTable('Configuration')->getConfiguration();
}

public function executeRightMenu() {
    Doctrine::getTable('Configuration')->getConfiguration();
}

public function executeLeftMenu() {
    Doctrine::getTable('Configuration')->getConfiguration();
}
```

...

I hope I can cache this call at request level, so that this query is not fired 40 times but 1 time.

Perhaps someone of you experts have a hint for me how to avoid that nasty repaeting sql query

Answer (score 2):

It's been some time I haven't used Symfony but if your menu is very much the same 99% of the time, why not put it into a configuration file instead of database (I find the xml/yml tree structure pretty good with this, and fast) ?

Or, if your table is not so big, save it into a global variable and reuse it everytime you are calling the configuration ?

Also, for Doctrine Result Caching, I've found this manual (corresponding to your symfony version): [Advanced Doctrine Usage](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/08-Advanced-Doctrine-Usage#chapter_08_using_doctrine_result_caching)

Comment: Thank you. After reading and reading i decided to use a singleton class. Your advises are good ways too. +1